# Power BI DAX Formula

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a PBI star schema model.  I'm trying to define a measure in the fact table using a numeric field (health index) that resides in one of the dimension tables and should correspond to the maximum date value (in the date dimension table) that is selected in the slicer.  The measure is not something that is aggregated.  A simple query joining the fact and dimension tables works fine and looks like this

| Country | Date | Health Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| China | 3/31/22 | 6 |
| China | 2/28/22 | 4 |
| China | 1/31/22 | 7 |

I want to be able to create a measure in the fact table called Current Health Index to display the data such that it shows the index value corresponding to the maximum date in the slicer, so if in the slicer the largest date selected is 3/31/22, I would like the measure to have a value of 6:

| Country | Date | Health Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| China | 3/31/22 | 6 |

I tried the following DAX formula but it gives me a very inflated value.  I know the joins are correct, so I don't know what the problem is:

```
Health Index Current = 
var _a = 
    MAXX(
        ALLSELECTED('Dim Date Table'[Date])
        ,'Dim Date Table'[Date]
    )

return 
   CALCULATE(
        MAX('Dim Health Indexes Table'[Health Index])
        ,'Dim Date Table'[Date] = _a
   )
```

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get a clear picture with you case, but I'll comment your measure and hope this will help.

```
Health Index Current = 
var _a = 
    MAXX(
        ALLSELECTED('Dim Date Table'[Date])
        ,'Dim Date Table'[Date]
    )  -- ALLSELECTED() removes an inner context.
       -- So, if you have only 1 layer of the context,
       -- then ALLSELECTED()=ALL(). 
       -- This can be the reason why you gets "very inflated value".
       -- First, I'd check _a value as measure. 

return 
   CALCULATE(
        MAX('Dim Health Indexes Table'[Health Index])
        ,'Dim Date Table'[Date] = _a
   ) -- This looks correct.
     -- You can try 'Dim Health Indexes Table'[Date]= _a
```

Try `'Dim Date Table'` or `VALUES(Dim Date Table'[Date])` instead of `ALLSELECTED('Dim Date Table'[Date])` and you'll get the max in the context.
Or try `VALUES('Dim Health Indexes Table'[Date])` instead of `ALLSELECTED('Dim Date Table'[Date])`

Comment: The number is not inflated, but what is happening is that it is displaying the value for the country that has the highes index value.  So if I filter the report for China, it is showing the health index value for Vietnam instead of China because Vietnam has the highest index for the maximum date I select in the slicer.  I want it to show China's value.  Hope this helps

Comment: did you check _a value, is it correct while filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Hello please try this measure:

VERSION-1

```
Health Index Current =
VAR _a =
    MAXX ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Dim Date Table'[Date] ), 'Dim Date Table'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Dim Health Indexes Table'[Health Index] ),
        'Dim Date Table'[Date] = _a,
        'Dim Health Indexes Table'[Country]
            = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Dim Health Indexes Table'[Country], "China" )
    )
```

VERSION-2

```
Health Index Current =
VAR _a =
    MAXX ( ALLSELECTED ( Dim Date Table[Date] ), Dim Date Table[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Dim Health Indexes Table[Health Index] ),
        FILTER (
            SUMMARIZE (
                Dim Health Indexes Table,
                -- First argument of summarize should be your fact table.
                Dim Health Indexes Table[Country],
                Dim Date Table[Date]
            ),
            Dim Date Table[Date] = _a
                && Dim Health Indexes Table[Country] = SELECTEDVALUE ( Dim Health Indexes Table[Country] )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't filter the DAX formula for a specific country.  I was just using China as the example.  The user could possibly select China from a slicer, or they can select all the countries or somewhere in between (i.e, multiple).

Comment: If only one country is selected, selectedvalue will take and use it. If Multiple countries is selected , say {China, Vietnam, Korea} then selected value will look to the 2nd argument and take it . and It will be the default value 'China'.  I hope I made it clear.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I can't hard code a country so that the formula defaults to something, especially if the defaulted country is not one to report on

Comment: Hi, This is not hardcoding. SELECTEDVALUE is a short for IF(HASONEVALUE(Tbl[Column]), VALUES(Tbl[Column]),"DefaultValue")

Comment: hi.  the country list can change at any time, so today china may be of interest but next month it may not.  Nonetheless, I tried what you said but it still extracts the latest index value for the country, regardless of the date selected in the slicer.  If I select 3/31/22 and 2/28/22, it will extract a value of 6, which is correct, but if I select 2/28/22 and 1/31/22, it will extract a value of 6, which is incorrect as it should extract 4 since the max date selected is 2/28/22.  Thanks

Comment: Ok. Good. What If you put the Var _a directly into the expression inside  calculate without defining it as var _a . the result will change ? If you want, I can update it as VERSION-2

Comment: Is this what you are saying? :
Health Index Current=CALCULATE(MAX( 'Dim Health Indexes Table'[Health Index] ),
'Dim Date Table'[Date]=MAXX (ALLSELECTED ('Dim Date Table'[Date] ), 'Dim Date Table' [Date])

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: thankt.  i tried this, but it still always defaults to showing the value that corresponds to the current value.  So if a country's value was 7 in Jan, then 4 in Feb, then 6 in Jan (like the chart above), it always shows a value of 6 regardless of the date range I select, as this is the most current value

Comment: I don't understand why It behaves like this. we need to search more. Keep in touch.

Comment: You're welcome. Stay Safe!

Comment: Hello I updated VERSION-2 . Can you please test it and let me know. Please check that first argument of summarize is your fact table. I assume that your fact table is Dim Health Indexes Table. If not, change it and test.

Comment: Thanks.  It still just defaults to showing the most current value, even if I select date range in the past.   so if I want to see the value for january, it is showing the value for March.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the feedback. In fact Var _a fetches the right max date, but after return part, some code structure are breaking it.

Comment: Hopefully my requirements are explained well.  Basically I only want to see the value of 6 if I happen to select 3/31/22 in the slicer.  If I select 3/31/22 and 2/28/22, I want to see two rows, one with the 6 and one with the 4 (with the corresponding dates).  If I select 2/28/22 and 1/31/22, I want to two rows, one with 4 and one with 7 (with the corresponding dates)

Comment: Yes, The fact is that my battery is dead now. I give up. Sometimes you need to know where to stop. Stay safe.

Comment: Apologies I am mistaken in my explanation.  If I select just 3/31/22 in the slicer, I want to see just one row showing the value of 6.  If I select 3/31/22 and 2/28/22 in the slicer, I still want to see just one row (not two) showing the value of 6 because 6 is the value from the max date in the slicer.  If I select 2/28/22 and 1/31 in the slicer, I still want to see one row (not two), showing the value of 4 since 4 is the value corresponding to the maximum date selected (2/28/22).  And if I select only 1/31/22 in the slicer, I want to see one row showing the value of 7. Thank you